# print() & matplitlib.pyplot.imshow() not synced in 'for' loop in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, printing, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to print a text corresponding each image n jupyter notebook cell. Below is a dummy code block:

```
 #paths = list of image paths; say 10 image-paths
 #document_text = list of strings as long as 200 words corresponding each image. say 10 strings

 %matplotlib inline
 import matplotlib.pylplot as plt
 from PIL import Image
 
 for path,text in enumerate(paths,document_text):
          print(document_text)
          img = Image.open(path)
          plt.imshow(img)
```

The code block works fine but with a glitch. All print statements gets printed & then all images gets displayed i.e 10 ~200 words strings followed by 10 images. What I wish to have is one print followed by the corresponding image. How can this be achieved? I don't wish to use plt.title() as strings are very long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to render each image with `plt.show()`:

```
for path,text in enumerate(paths,document_text):
    print(document_text)
    img = Image.open(path)
    plt.imshow(img)
    plt.show()
```